# href with link to anchor # throws jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

When linking [from this page](http://www.thejasonwilson.com/work/greekcreations.php) to my [homepage](http://www.thejasonwilson.com/index.php#home) from the main navigation on my site I am getting this error:

```
`Uncaught Error: jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, 
unrecognized expression: ../index.php#home
at Function.st.error (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
at ft (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
at wt (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
at Function.st [as find] (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
at init.find (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
at new init (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
at b (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (main.js:201)
at Function.each (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
at init.each (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)`
```

Here are some of the links:

```
<a href='../index.php#home'><span>Home</span></a>
<a href="../index.php#about"><span>About</span></a>
<a href="../index.php#work"><span>Work</span></a>
```

The links are working correctly, and are jumping to the different sections between pages, but the JavaScript errors are bothering me.

I'm still pretty novice to JavaScript and jQuery, but I'm working very hard to learn it and become proficient. I'm just not there yet. I'm guessing that this is because the link has the "#" in it and the jQuery doesn't like it, but any thoughts on what's causing it and how I could fix it would be very appreciated.

Comment: What jQuery statements are throwing error?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7pzas9d2/  however as your question is, this question is off topic as it does not provide enough information in the question, itself, to express what the issue is.

Comment: @SaifUrRahman very sorry, I'm new here and this was my very first post. I updated it to include the JS error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I quickly click through the navigation, I see the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $target is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (main.js:31)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
```

Even there is jquery referenced in the stack-trace, this error happens independently from jQuery and is an error in JavaScript - read more about this error here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined

This particular stack trace you can read from bottom up - so you will see that an event was handled and dispatched within jquery-1.9.1.min.js line 3 (Lines in a minified resource are useless most of the time) then an anonymous function in your main.js was called and crashed on line 31.

The excerpt of this line is as follows:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(document).off("scroll");

  $('a').each(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  })
  $(this).addClass('active');

  var target = this.hash;
  $target = $(target); # this is line 31
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
  }, 500, 'swing', function () {
    window.location.hash = target;
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
  });
});
```

In your case it looks like you just missed to declare the variable `$target`. Just put a `var` in front of `$target` like:

```
var $target = $(target);
```

And your function should work well.

By the way, there is a nice way to debug. Just add a `debugger;`-expression close to where the error happens and you will see in depth debug information. Like:

[image: Debug output]

---

Addition:

If you check the other error you have:

```
Uncaught Error: jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, 
unrecognized expression: ../index.php#home
at Function.st.error (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
at ft (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
at wt (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
at Function.st [as find] (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
at init.find (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
at new init (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
at b (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (main.js:201)
at Function.each (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
at init.each (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
```

There is the `at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (main.js:201)` in the trace where the problem actually starts. Usually you can expect that the bug very, very rarely is in jQuery. More often your input just crashes there.

In your case. Lets check main.js:201:

```
  //nav-active
  function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.menu-list a').each(function () {
      var currentLink = $(this);
      var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href")); # this is line 201
      if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
        $('.menu-list a').removeClass("active");
        currentLink.addClass("active");
      }
      else{
        currentLink.removeClass("active");
      }
    });
  }
```

Let's have a look at line 201:

```
var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
```

here we can check what we have in `currentLink.attr("href")` obviously (from the error message) - ../index.php#home - so you are trying to create an element with the following selector: `$('../index.php#home')` instead I guess you were trying to do `$('#home')` - if so, just update your snippet like this:

```
  //nav-active
  function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.menu-list a').each(function () {
      var currentLink = $(this);
      var linkHref = currentLink.attr("href"); // extract the href attribute from link
      var anchor = linkHref.split("#").pop(); // split by # and take the last part
      var refElement = $("#" + anchor); // use the anchor extract to use it as id selector

      // add refElement.length check - to just continue if the element actually exist
      if (refElement.length && refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
        $('.menu-list a').removeClass("active");
        currentLink.addClass("active");
      }
      else{
        currentLink.removeClass("active");
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I added the var and that seems to have resolved that $target issue. I will use that debugger expression going forward so thanks for that. I'm still getting the "Uncaught error message". I modified my original post to include the JS error that I'm getting. My jquery is minified. Does this mean there really is no way to resolve this other than removing anchor IDs from my hrefs?

Comment: @Jason I have updated the answer and added the explanation and a possible solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

> it Looks like your jquery library is not loaded, you are trying to use
>   the library before loading it.

try including in head element like below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```